# How to work around an early async return while getting AngularJS to wait before updating the UI?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-promise

I have a function that reloads the list of items on a dashboard that looks like the below snippet:

```js
// Code goes here

angular
  .module('example', [])
  .directive('list', list)
var fooCount = 3;

function list($timeout, $q) {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    controllerAs: "vm",
    template: `
        <button ng-click="vm.updateFoos()">update foos</button>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="foo in vm.fooList">{{foo.ticketNum}}</li>
        </ul>
    `,
    bindToController: true,
    controller($scope) {
      const fooList = [{
        ticketNum: 1
      }, {
        ticketNum: 2
      }, {
        ticketNum: 3
      }];
      const vm = Object.assign(this, {
        fooList,
        updateFoos
      });

      function updateFoos() {
        return $timeout(() => {
          vm.fooList = [];
          return vm.fooList;
        }).then(() => {
          return getAllFoos().then(foos => {
            vm.fooList = foos;
            return foos;
          });
        });
      }
      updateFoos()
    }
  }
  //example only, returns a promise of items
  function getAllFoos() {
    // imitates save functionality I don't control
    $timeout(() => {
      fooCount = fooCount + 1;
    }, 1000)
    const fooList = [...Array(fooCount).keys()].slice(fooCount - 3).map(num => {
      return {
        'ticketNum': num
      }
    });
    return $q.resolve(fooList)
  }
  return directive;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="example">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <list></list>
</body>

</html>
```

I cannot get the list to update in my app - it works here. I've tried wrapping various parts in a timeout, and making sure the real chain of promises return from every part. I find that when I refresh and it is called again, it gets the list correctly from the server.

If I pause in the dev console, in the timeout, I get the results updated on my screen.

My real version of get all foos returns a promise, like the example above. If I put a breakpoint anywhere in the code, it will update the UI as intended.

What would cause the list to not update?

Comment: Why do you use $timeout() to populate foos?

Comment: Create a plunker or codesandbox that reproduces problem

Comment: @MarcusHöglund it was an attempt to make sure that the code inside had a digest loop after it. I know *rationally* it doesn't need it but I was getting desperate.

Comment: @charlietfl I can try and do that but I'd end up re-implementing a lot of the web app.

Comment: @georgeawg I actually didn't. I copied some of it from another question on SO. Maybe they copeid it from plunkr? In the real version it's (*double checks*) AngularJS promises all the way down

Comment: @georgeawg it turns out the service I'm calling (called here getAllFoos) is returning early with old data. I've updated the question and I'm going to self answer.

Comment: @georgeawg it does now, have you checked?

Comment: The real `getAllFoos()` is returning a promise that is prematurely resolving. We can't fix the problem with `getAllFoos()` if we can see the code for it. Provide a MVCE of the real `getAllFoos()` that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @georgeawg the real `getAllFoos` is a database service outside of my control.

Comment: A callback based API can be converted to a promise-based API. I have yet to see a service that can't be integrated into the AngularJS framework.

Comment: @georgeawg if it returns 'early' under the hood, you have no way of knowing when it's finished.

Answer (score -1):

## WARNING - this answer provides a work around only.

#### A real solution involves fixing `getAllFoos`.

The issue was that the `getAllFoos` was returning old code early. I tried to recreate that in the question.

The solution is to just wait for an arbitrary amount of time until the service returns.

```js
// Code goes here

angular
  .module('example', [])
  .directive('list', list)
var fooCount = 4;

const ASYNC_WAIT_TIME = 1001;

function list($timeout, $q) {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    controllerAs: "vm",
    template: `
        <button ng-click="vm.updateFoos()">update foos</button>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="foo in vm.fooList">{{foo.ticketNum}}</li>
        </ul>
    `,
    bindToController: true,
    controller($scope) {
      const fooList = [{
        ticketNum: 1
      }, {
        ticketNum: 2
      }, {
        ticketNum: 3
      }];
      const vm = Object.assign(this, {
        fooList,
        updateFoos
      });

      function updateFoos() {
        $timeout(() => {
          return getAllFoos();
        }, ASYNC_WAIT_TIME).then(foos => {
          vm.fooList = foos;
          return foos;
        });
      }
      updateFoos()
    }
  }
  //example only, returns a promise of items
  function getAllFoos() {
    $timeout(() => {
      fooCount = fooCount + 1;
    }, 1000)
    const fooList = [...Array(fooCount).keys()].slice(fooCount - 3).map(num => {
      return {
        'ticketNum': num
      }
    });
    return $q.resolve(fooList)
  }
  return directive;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="example">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <list></list>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The use of `$timeout` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom a deeper problem which is not being addressed. While adding an arbitrary timeout may get the code to work, it is not a robust solution.

Comment: @georgeawg and boy do I know it. Should I emphasize that more in the answer? I hate having to have done this in the code. But this is a valid bandaid I think.